# what cause NA when convert value in r?

Tags: r

In df, has a factor column as below:

```
q5
A
1
B
1
```

i want to convert the `A B` to `0`
`df$q5<-as.character(df$q5)`

`df$q5[df$q5!=1]<-0`

but result is:

```
q5
NA
1
NA
1
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Please use `dput()` for sharing data when you use the `r` tag. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: I'm guessing the `as.character` line never got run. I can replicate your results by skipping that line. The problem is you are working with a `factor`, which is a categorical variable which you can't add new groups to like you did. If you convert via `as.character` as you show, it all works fine.

Comment: If you change `q5` to character first, it should work. To keep it factor, you can't change the levels with assignment to the vector; you'd have to assign to the levels themselves: `levels(df$q5)[levels(df$q5) != 1] <- 0`. The forcats package makes this simpler: `forcats::fct_collapse(df$q5, '0' = c('A', 'B'))` Regardless, you should convert to integer/numeric afterwards. If it's a factor, use `as.integer(as.character(df$q5))` to avoid inadvertently grabbing the integers which factors are stored as.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `recode` to change the `levels` of a `factor` column instead of converting to `character` and then change it.

```
library(car)
df$q5 <- recode(df$q5, "c('A', 'B') = 0")
df$q5
#[1] 0 1 0 1
#Levels: 0 1
```

Comment: I am still confused, what's the problem in my script?

Comment: @Angelia.Megan  Here I am showing a way to convert the values to 0 without changing it to `character` class.  Based on the example and your code, it works fine with me.

Comment: thanks!your script works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not reproducible.

```
df <- read.table(con<-file("clipboard"),header=T)

df$q5.char <- as.character(df$q5)

df$q5.char[df$q5.char!=1] <- 0
```

> ```
>   q5 q5.char
> 1  A       0
> 2  1       1
> 3  B       0
> 4  1       1
> ```